# xsltproc: doctype for docbook

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I have an XSLT style sheet that generates DocBook XML. I used `xsl:output` to generate a DOCTYPE declartion for the docbook

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
              doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
             encoding="utf-8"
             indent="no" />
```

The resulting XML file has an extra empty string, so xmllint complains:

```
/path/docbk.xml:2: parser error : Content error in the external subset
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN" ""><book>
^
```

Is this an issue with xsltproc or with the XSLT stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SGML allows a DOCTYPE with only a PUBLIC identifier, but XML *requires* a system identifier - you can have either a system ID alone or a public ID and a system ID, but not just the public one.  [The docbook guide](http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/ch02.html) suggests

```
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
               "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
```

which would correspond to

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
            doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd"
            encoding="utf-8"
            indent="no" />
```

In fact, `xsltproc` *does* have a bug here, but not the one you think.  From [the spec for `xsl:output`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method):

> **If the `doctype-system` attribute is specified, the xml output method should output a document type declaration** immediately before the first element. The name following `<!DOCTYPE` should be the name of the first element. If `doctype-public` attribute is also specified, then the xml output method should output PUBLIC followed by the public identifier and then the system identifier; otherwise, it should output SYSTEM followed by the system identifier. The internal subset should be empty. **The `doctype-public` attribute should be ignored unless the `doctype-system` attribute is specified.**

(my bold)